# changing the backcolor of selected tab

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Invoices, Orders,Estimates,Reports,Settings are the various tabs,

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name == "CompanyTab")
{
     tabControl1.SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;  
}
```

but this changes the color of tab-page not the color of tab .

Comment: You can do it with javascript like that;

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746008

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1565699).